# Display Array in javascript Maze

Tags: javascript

Here is JavaScript data representing the maze i am trying to create. Each "W" is a wall, "S" marks the start position, and "F" marks the finish. Spaces are empty cells that the player can walk through. Using divs in my html for the cells and each row of the maze a div using display flex. But when try to create maze in javascript nothing appears. Here is code

```js
const map = [
  "WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW",
  "W   W     W     W W W",
  "W W W WWW WWWWW W W W",
  "W W W   W     W W   W",
  "W WWWWWWW W WWW W W W",
  "W         W     W W W",
  "W WWW WWWWW WWWWW W W",
  "W W   W   W W     W W",
  "W WWWWW W W W WWW W F",
  "S     W W W W W W WWW",
  "WWWWW W W W W W W W W",
  "W     W W W   W W W W",
  "W WWWWWWW WWWWW W W W",
  "W       W       W   W",
  "WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW",
];

map.forEach(function(arr, index) {
  arr.forEach(function(path, i) {
    var span = document.createElement("span");
    if (path === "W") {
      span.textContent = " ";
      span.style.backgroundColor = "darkblue";
    }
    if (path === " ") {
      span.textContent = " ";
      span.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    }
    if (path === F) {
      span.textContent = "finished";
      span.style.backgroundColor = "darkblue";
      span.style.color = "white";
    }
    document.body.appendChild(span)
  });
  document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("br"))
});
```

[image]

Comment: your code does not reflect your data: your `map` is an array of strings, not an array of arrays, so when you do `map.forEach(arr...` that argument name "lies" about what you're working with. At the very least use `map.forEach(function(string, pos) { string.forEach(function (letter) { ... }); });`. But on a Stackoverflow posting note: make this is a runnable snippet, so you can show off what happens instead (and _remember to run it_, to confirm your code doesn't have obvious errors, first)

Comment: I made you a shorter version using ES6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things

1. You do not have an array unless you split the row
2. You did not quote your "F"
3. You need to fill the span with something. I use a wide space char
4. I had to add "S" to the white path

```js
const map = [
  "WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW",
  "W   W     W     W W W",
  "W W W WWW WWWWW W W W",
  "W W W   W     W W   W",
  "W WWWWWWW W WWW W W W",
  "W         W     W W W",
  "W WWW WWWWW WWWWW W W",
  "W W   W   W W     W W",
  "W WWWWW W W W WWW W F",
  "S     W W W W W W WWW", 
  "WWWWW W W W W W W W W",
  "W     W W W   W W W W",
  "W WWWWWWW WWWWW W W W",
  "W       W       W   W",
  "WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW",
];
const fSpace = "  "; // from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space
map.forEach(function(row, index) {
  const arr = row.split("");
  arr.forEach(function(path, i) {
    var span = document.createElement("span");
    if (path === "W") {
      span.textContent = fSpace; // " ";
      span.style.backgroundColor = "darkblue";
    }
    if (path === " " || path === "S") {
      span.textContent = fSpace; //" ";
      span.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    }
    if (path === "F") {
      span.textContent = "finished";
      span.style.backgroundColor = "darkblue";
      span.style.color = "white";
    }
    document.body.appendChild(span)
  });
  document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("br"))
});
```

Perhaps better:

```js
const map = `WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
             W   W     W     W W W
             W W W WWW WWWWW W W W
             W W W   W     W W   W
             W WWWWWWW W WWW W W W
             W         W     W W W
             W WWW WWWWW WWWWW W W
             W W   W   W W     W W
             W WWWWW W W W WWW W F
             S     W W W W W W WWW 
             WWWWW W W W W W W W W
             W     W W W   W W W W
             W WWWWWWW WWWWW W W W
             W       W       W   W
             WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW`.split("\n");
             
const fSpace = "  "; 
map.forEach((row, index) => {
  row.trim().split("").forEach((path, i) => {
    var span = document.createElement("span");
    span.textContent = fSpace; // default
    span.classList.toggle("blue", path === "W");
    if (path === "S") {
      span.classList.add("start");
      span.textContent = "Start";
    }
    else if (path === "F") {
      span.classList.add("finish");
      span.textContent = "End";
    }
    document.body.appendChild(span);
  });
  document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("br"))
});
```

```css
span {
  display:inline-block;
  color: black;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}

.blue {
  background-color: darkblue;
}
.start {  background-color: red; }
.finish {  background-color: green; }
```